# How to get embedded ICC profile of image in java

Tags: java, jpeg, imaging, color-profile, color-management

I am processing jpegs with different ICC profiles. Since I load them the embedded ICC profiles are deleted. But i need them afterwards.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instances of `java.awt.BufferedImage`, you can use `getColorModel()`:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getColorModel()

Does that work for you?... or, does your image-loading involve more exotic datastructures?